# Spark not picking up hadoop conf

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, YARN_CONF_DIR all defined in the spark-env.sh script. However, when I try to load a sparksession on yarn with

`val sess = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("default")`

It times out

```
23:36:44.219 [run-main-0] DEBUG o.a.h.i.retry.RetryInvocationHandler - Exception while invoking getClusterMetrics of class ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl over null. Retrying after sleeping for 30000ms.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-10-122-2-155/10.122.2.155 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

There's nothing running locally with port 8032 open so it obviously times out.

my yarn-site.xml explicitly states that the RM address

```
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
      <value>10.122.2.195:8032</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: Usually spark-session loads the SparkConf and the SQLContext for you.  When you run spark-session, do you not see those items in the stdout?

Comment: I don't see anything about them in the output

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant spark-shell.  Are you running this as a spark-submit or are you invoking the shell?  I assumed the latter, but realize in retrospect this may be wrong.

Comment: Ok, Are you using Spark 2.0?  I think what may be happening if you are is that you don't need to explicitly create the SparkConf and Context, as they are encapsulated in the SparkSession if you instantiate with a builder().

Comment: @tadamhicks yes I'm using 2.0.2. I tried using the SparkSession.builder().master("yarn") and came across this same error

Comment: Not according to Databricks https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html

Comment: what I tried above did not work either

Comment: Try `<property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>10.122.2.195</value>
    </property>`. Make sure **10.122.2.155** should able to connect RM without password.

Comment: That does not help either. I'm able to connect to the resourcemanager without a password. Spark thinks the host is 0.0.0.0 for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Your driver program is not able to access the variables defined in spark-env.sh. 
(Assuming you are not running spark-shell)

The possible reason could be, the user running the driver is different than the user of spark(spark installation files).

Try manually setting the variables of spark-env.sh before running your driver as follows

```
source spark-env.sh
```

Comment: So I tried this and the vars are set. I then went into `sbt console` to build the session manually and still get a 0.0.0.0/8032 connection timeout with master `yarn-client`.

Comment: I have two questions. 1. how are you running the driver? 2. could try with yarn-cluster mode?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding the following lines to the `build.sbt` file.

```
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += file("/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop")

unmanagedClasspath in Runtime += file("/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop")
```

With the other environment variables accounted for this allowed the sbt project to pick up the yarn configuration.